# Can I SET a map in Neo4j Cypher without overwriting existing properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a map say

```
car: {make: toyota, color: blue, model: camry}
```

and I have a node `Car` with the property

```
make: toyota
```

Now I want to add the properties in the map car to my node `Car`.

However,

```
MATCH (n:Car {make:'toyota'}) 
SET n +=car 
RETURN n;
```

will overwrite the make property on my node.

Is there a way I can avoid it doing this?

The use case is when make is the key property for the node I wouldn't want it to be accidentally changed and of course I wouldn't want to trow an error  either.

Comment: Of Interest: [Mutate specific properties using a map and +=](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/#set-setting-properties-using-map)

Answer (score 0):

You can use apoc.map.clean to remove certain keys and values from a map:

`SET c += apoc.map.clean(car, ['make'],[])`

Comment: So this would leave the car property [make] undisturbed? basically is the apoc removing 'make'  from the map before executing the SET?

Comment: Yes. If you want to remove all existing keys from the map (so that the update operation only adds new properties and doesn't overwrite existing properties) you can supply the keys on that node as the keys to remove from the map: `SET c += apoc.map.clean(car, keys(c), [])`

Comment: I will test these